# Surfaces in Petrel 2010.1 in black and white

Tags: 3d, maps, surface, petrel

When I loading surfaces it is appears in black and white in 3D windows but in 2D windows the colors exist how can show the color for the surface in 3D windows?

Answer (score 0):

Its your graphic card issue. This normally happened in 3D window viewer. U will not be able to set the color as Z-values, it will appear as white surface. But if you choose as specific color, it will appear same as color that you set in info tab. Hope that helps.